# Laravel eloquont query takes long time to fetch data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a query just to retrieve the data, when I try to fetch 10k data from below query it will take more than 1.7mins. It that reasonable or how can I improve this time.

```
Vehicles::leftJoin('vehicle_details', 'vehicle_details.id', 'vehicles.vehi_details_id')
        ->leftJoin('vehicle_extras', 'vehicle_extras.vehicle_id','vehicles.id')
        ->leftJoin('reasons', 'reasons.vehicle_id', 'vehicles.id')
        ->leftJoin('revised_vehicles', 'revised_vehicles.vehicle_id','vehicles.id')
        ->leftJoin('makes', 'makes.model_id', 'vehicle_details.model_id')
        ->leftJoin('bidder_invoices', 'bidder_invoices.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
        ->leftJoin('bidding_views', 'bidding_views.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
        ->leftJoin('bidder_prs', 'bidder_prs.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
        ->leftJoin('bidder_remarks', 'bidder_remarks.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
        ->leftJoin('vehicle_pins', 'vehicle_pins.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
        ->leftJoin('translations', 'translations.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')          
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('vehicles.approve', '=', 1)
                ->orWhereNull('vehicles.approve');
        })
        ->orderBy('vehicles.site', 'ASC')
        ->orderBy('vehicles.auc_time', 'ASC')
        ->select([
            'vehicles.*',
            'vehicle_details.color as vehi_color',
            'vehicle_details.grade as vehi_grade',
            'vehicle_details.images',
            'makes.model_name',
            'vehicle_extras.id as extra_details_id',
            'vehicle_extras.ic_remarks',
            'vehicle_extras.bidder_adj',
            'reasons.fob_issue',
            'reasons.fob_approve',
            'reasons.decline_remark',
            'reasons.tc_issue',
            'reasons.fob_overruling_remark',
            'bidder_invoices.invoice_name',
            'bidding_views.reason as bidder_reason',
            'bidder_prs.bidder_mb as bidder_mb',
            'bidder_remarks.bidder_remarks as bidder_remarks_daily',
            'revised_vehicles.old_mb_round',
            'translations.assigned_translator'
        ])
        ->paginate(10000);
```

I have also added indexes for every join column. Also I have used MySQL as my DB

Comment: It's very tough to say without knowing your schema or dbms (mysql or postgres).  Can you provide the query plan for the above query?

Comment: @Matthew I have used MySQL, I will update the question with details

Comment: Also, you are paginating `10.000` results... NEVER DO THAT, lot of memory and only that will take a lot of time... Even the browser will have a hard time trying to display 10k results...

Comment: @matiaslauriti Do you have any specific recommendations or resources on how OP should structure their query to achieve the result they're looking for?  Since OP didn't mention what they're using the data for it's not possible to know whether a 10,000 record result set is a problem or not, or whether there is a more efficient way of structuring the program.

Comment: @Matthew I do not, only experience... OP can do whatever he wants, no doubt about that, it is just frustrating seeing a lot of SO posts with so really bad code for production applications... I know this is not a tutorial page, but is infuriating... You have the magic of Eloquent and people create monstruos queries... absolute madness...

Comment: I guess it's unfortunate that questions and code aren't up to your standard @matiaslauriti, but most people post questions on StackOverflow to improve their situation, so any tangible advice you can give I'm sure OP would be grateful for.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I just add `10k` to check the speed of the query. Also, I have tried with `1500` for pagination. It takes around `1.5s` to `5s`.  Is that reasonable?

Comment: You never show more than 100, it could be 500 at most, basic UI/UX: 5, 10, 25, 50 per page

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Eloquent relationships as methods in your Eloquent model classes refer [Eloquent Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)
if the relation is 1:1 use hasOne
if the relationship is 1:M use has Many
if the relationship is M:1 use belongs to

in your Vehicle model

for example

for 1:1

```
public function vehicleDetails() {
    return $this->hasOne(VehicleDetail::class,'vehi_details_id','id');
}
```

for 1:M

```
public function VehicleExtras() {
    return $this->hasMany(VehicleExtras::class,'id','vehicle_id');
}
```

for M:1

```
public function VehicleMakes() {
    return $this->belongsTo(VehicleMakes::class,'model_id','model_id');
}
```

and after making all the relationship you can get the vehicle table with your filters as follows

```php
$data['vehicles'] = Vehicles::whereNull('vehicles.deleted_at')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('vehicles.multiple_po', 0)
                ->orWhereNull('vehicles.multiple_po');
        })
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('vehicles.approve', '=', 1)
                ->orWhereNull('vehicles.approve');
        })
        ->orderBy('vehicles.site', 'ASC')
        ->orderBy('vehicles.auc_time', 'ASC')
        ->paginate(10000);
```

then,

you can the vehicles in the blade as normal and if you needed to call the relationship table belongs to a certain id,

to get a description from vehicle details you can access as follows

```
$data['vehicles']->vehicleDetails->description
```

or to get the of a make of the vehicle from the makes table

```
$data['vehicles']->VehicleMakes->name
```